# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 MergeSort

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to implement MergeSort Algorithm in Java using eclipse IDE.
I am getting following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

It contains three methods: `merge()`, `mergeSort()` and `printArray()`

```
public class MergeSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = { 10, 5, 3, 7, 6, 2, 21, 4 };

        mergeSort(numbers);
        printArray(numbers);

    }

    public static int[] mergeSort(int[] A) {
        int n = A.length;

        if (n < 2) {
            return A;
        }
        int mid = n / 2;

        int[] left = new int[mid];
        int[] right = new int[n - mid];

        for (int i = 0; i < mid - 1; i++) {
            left[i] = A[i];
        }

        for (int i = mid; i < n - 1; i++) {
            right[i - mid] = A[i];
        }

        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);
        merge(left, right);
        return A;
    }

    public static int[] merge(int[] A, int[] B) {
        int[] C = new int[A.length + B.length];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;

        int nL = A.length;
        int nR = B.length;

        while (i < nL && j < nR) {
            if (A[i] <= B[j]) {
                C[k] = A[i];
                k = k + 1;
                i = i + 1;
            } else {
                C[k] = A[j];
                j = j + 1;
            }
            k = k + 1;
        }

        while (i < nL) {
            C[k] = A[i];
            i = i + 1;
            k = k + 1;
        }

        while (j < nR) {
            C[k] = B[j];
            j = j + 1;
            k = k + 1;
        }
        return C;
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] A) {
          for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(A[i]);
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: on array split, you should write `for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++)` (not `i < mid - 1`) and `for (int i = mid; i < n; i++)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `while` loop in the `merge()` method is faulty. You're assigning `A[j]` to `C[k]`, while it should be `B[j]`. Also, you're incrementing `k` twice for `if` condition.

Change the while loop to:

```
while (i < nL && j < nR) {
  if (A[i] <= B[j]) {
    C[k] = A[i];
    i = i + 1;
  } else {
    C[k] = B[j];
    j = j + 1;
  }
  k = k + 1;
}
```

But, apart from this issue, there are other issues with your code.

Firstly, your looping range is not correct. Currently you're missing out `(mid - 1)`<sup>th</sup> and `(n - 1)`<sup>th</sup> element. Change your loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
    left[i] = A[i];
}

for (int i = mid; i < n; i++) {
    right[i - mid] = A[i];
}
```

Secondly, your `mergeSort()` method creates a new array. You are not using the return value currently. Re-assign the return value to `left` and `right` respectively:

```
left = mergeSort(left);
right = mergeSort(right);
return merge(left, right);
```

And finally, the final result also you need to re-assign to `numbers` array:

```
numbers = mergeSort(numbers);
printArray(numbers);
```

Comment: There is also mistake in array splitting.

Comment: @AhmedAdnan Did you get the correct result? I see other issues also, which I left for you to solve.

Comment: no , I am struggling with them to solve . Its not sorting array at all. Can you please help?